# Is it possible to use a variable string before .delete in Django models

Tags: python, django, variables, delete-row

Conceptually, I want to do this:

```
deletestring = graphname+'.objects.filter('+graphname+'aid_id='+myid+')'
deletestring.delete()
```

where graphname and myid are variables, but this gives me a 'str' object has no attribute 'delete' AttributeError. How do I change this to tell python/Django to use my string to delete the matching records from the model? Thanks!

UPDATE:
Thanks to Shang Wang, part of the problem is solved.

```
# This works
graphname = 'g5'
modelnamevar = apps.get_model('nbig', graphname)
modelnamevar.objects.filter(g5aid_id=myid).delete()   

# This does not work:
graphname = 'g5'
modelnamevar = apps.get_model('nbig', graphname)
myfieldname = graphname + 'aid_id'
modelnamevar.objects.filter(myfieldname=myid).delete()
```

I get a message "Cannot resolve keyword 'myfieldname' into a field. 
Is it possible to convert this string so that it will be recognized as a field name? Thanks!

Comment: is graphname the name of a model you've defined?

Comment: Yes, graphname is the variable that holds my model name and it is also the prefix of a field of the model (for example: graphname = 'g2', field name = 'g2aid_id')

Comment: Just use `exec`... /s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django you could get a model from a string using:

```
from django.apps import apps
Model = apps.get_model(app_label='your-app-label', model_name='graphname')
```

Django doc about [get_model function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model).

<sub>By the way, don't use string to compose a program, it's not going to execute.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

With the help of another post, I found this will work:

```
modelname='g5'
modelnamevar = apps.get_model('nbig', modelname)
myfield = modelname + 'aid_id'
kwargs = {myfield: myid}
modelnamevar.objects.filter(**kwargs).delete()
```